# Appending a string to __FUNCTION__ in a macro

Tags: c++, macros

Please pardon me if I am asking an obvious question,
but after going through a bunch of threads and trying out stuff, I am not able to pin down this simple thing.

I have this small program:

```
#define FUNC_PREFIX __FUNCTION__ "() :"

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", FUNC_PREFIX);
    return 0;
}
```

So I can pass `FUNC_PREFIX` instead of `__FUNCTION__` to log functions and they will print the calling function name followed by paren and colon — just so to improve readability of log line outputs.

This compiles fine as-is in Visual Studio 2008.
But in `g++`, I get an error expected ‘)’ before string constant

I tried a few things like doing:

```
#define TEMP __FUNCTION__ 
#define FUNC_PREFIX TEMP "() :"
```

but to no avail.

What is the way to go about doing this?

Comment: If the logging code knows it is passed a function name, the correct place to add the parentheses and colon is in the logging code.  If the logging code doesn't know that it's getting a function name, then you probably need more information than just the function name and can format that to include the parentheses.  Note that the accepted answer using `#define FUNC_PREFIX __func__,"() :"` cannot be used in many places other than a `printf`-family function.  For example, `strcpy(buffer, FUNC_PREFIX)` won't compile but `strcpy(buffer, (FUNC_PREFIX))` will — but it won't do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your printf is missing a quote. Use identifier `__func__` and you can print two strings if you define the macro as:

```
#define FUNC_PREFIX __func__,"() :"

int main()
{
    printf("%s %s\n", FUNC_PREFIX);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the quote part - had forgotten to include that while posting the question.

Answer (score 9):

`__FUNCTION__` is not a macro in either standard C or standard C++.

Both C++ 2011 (§8.4 Function definitions, and §8.4.1 In general) and C 1999 or 2011 have a pre-defined identifier `__func__` which is the name of the function.  It is not a macro, so you would not be able to concatenate a string with it in the preprocessor.

So, you will have to revise your code if it is to work with standard-compliant C or C++ compilers that do not support the MSVS extension.

---

GCC manual (for version 4.6.1) has section §6.47 Function names as strings.  It documents that `__FUNCTION__` is a synonym for `__func__`.  It also discusses `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`.  These are not preprocessor macros.  So, you will have to adapt your code to work correctly with `gcc` or `g++`.